# Python замена всех URL-адресов в строке на другие ссылки, исключая .png, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg

Tags: python, исключения, url, re

Поделитесь опытом, как добавить в строку исключения для окончаний URL-адресов для .png, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg ?

````
str = """
La-la-la https://example.ru https://example.jpg/
https://example.com/ la-la-la https://example.com/
la-la-la https://example.png/ la-la-la
"""
print (re.sub(r'http([^\.\s]+\.[^\.\s]*)+[^\.\s]{2,}' , f'https://oter.new.com', str)))```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужны исключения по конкретному виду файлов:

```
import re
ext = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', ]
print(re.sub('https?://[^\s/?]+', lambda m: 'https://oter.new.com'
             if m.group(0).lower().split('.')[-1] not in ext else m.group(0), text))
```

Если же нужно для большинства известных типов файлов, то можно так.
Могу предложить такой вариант через сопоставление окончания домена с mime-типом, как более универсальный вариант:

```
import mimetypes
import re
print(re.sub('https?://[^\s/?]+', lambda m: 'https://oter.new.com' 
             if not mimetypes.guess_type('f.{}'.format(m.group(0).lower().split('.')[-1]))[0] else m.group(0), text))
```